# Battlefield 3 last patch: weapons efficiency decreased?

Tags: battlefield-3

Playing BF3 on XBOX360 after yesterday's patch, I noticed that my efficiency in killing enemies decreased.

It is not about aiming, I had a concrete sensation that every weapon is less effective than  it was before the patch.

I was aware of the fact that USAS-12 was due to be nerfed (and indeed it has been, especially if you consider fragmentation ammo); now even if a shot hits an enemy in plain face at a distance slightly greater than extremely close range, that shot alone doesn't kill him. This is very different from USAS-12 previous behavior.

But after the patch it seems that using every weapon has increased its level of difficulty.

Am I having the right perception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that a good portion of the weapons have had *some* change to them. You can check out the changes in the patch notes here: http://blogs.battlefield.com/2012/04/xbox-360-patch-going-live-april-3rd/

So to answer the question: it probably depends on which weapon/s you mostly use and get used against you. For example, the M16A4 has had its vertical recoil increased, but horizontal recoil decreased, while the M416 has not changed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in complete agreement with your observations. I actually think they tweaked the entire ballistics system which has effected every class of weapon. I used to be able to enter a hostile environment with guns blazing and would be somewhat successful. Now I have to be much more defensive as every gun is much more sensitive to the damage it causes. It's completely changed the game but it does seem more accurate.